# Can't find element using Selenium CSS Selector even though it works fine individually

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this page: "https://www.semi.org/en/resources/member-directory"

On it's own, the code seems to work fine:
`link = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__title").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')` 
This returns my link. However, when I nest the code in a for loop, I get an error that the css selector was unable to find the element. I tried using the X_Path, but that would only access the first container.

This is my code:

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame({'Company Name': [], 'Join Date': [], 'Company ID': [],'Company Description': [], 'Link': [], 'Primary Industry': [], 
                           'Primary Product Category': [], 'Primary Sub Product Category': [], 'Keywords': [], 'Address':[]})

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# Load the desired URL
another_url = "https://www.semi.org/en/resources/member-directory"
browser.get(another_url)
time.sleep(3)


containers = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
for i in range(len(containers)):
    container = containers[i]
    link = container.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
    browser.get(link)
    print("Page navigated after click" + browser.title)
    time.sleep(3)
    company_name =  browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-title").text
    try:
        join_date = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__join-date").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'span').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        join_date = "None"
    try:
        c_ID = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__company-id").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'span').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        c_ID = "None"
    try:
        company_description = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__description").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        company_description = "None" 
    try:
        company_link = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"member-company__website").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').get_attribute('href')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        company_link = "None"
    try:
        primary_industry = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__primary-industry").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        primary_industry = "None"
    try:
        primary_product_cat = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__primary-product-category").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        primary_product_cat = "None"
    try:
        primary_sub_product_cat = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__primary-product-subcategory").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        primary_sub_product_cat = "None"
    
    try:
        keywords = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "member-company__keywords ").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        keywords = "None"
    try:
        address = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"member-company__address").text.replace("Street Address","")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        address = "None"
    browser.get(another_url)

    time.sleep(5)

    result_df = pd.DataFrame({"Company Name": [company_name], 
        "Join Date": [join_date],
        "Company ID": [c_ID],
        "Company Description": [company_description],
        "Company Website": [company_link],
        "Primary Industry": [primary_industry],
        "Primary Product Category": [primary_product_cat],
        "Primary Sub Product Category": [primary_sub_product_cat],
        "Keywords": [keywords],
        "Address":[address]})
    results_df = pd.concat([results_df, result_df])
    results_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    results_df.to_csv('semi_test', index=False)

browser.close()
```

What's going on?

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly due to the statement `containers = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')`.
If you print out the containers, you'll notice that the first row selected is the header which contains no links and your script will fail giving the exception that you're seeing.
You can fix this with `containers = containers[1:]` but you'll then face the problem of `StaleElementReferenceException` because you've come back to the home page after opening another link.
You should scrape all the links from the page at once, and then iterate over those to scrape each of them, rather than coming back to the home page over and over again.

Comment: Thank you - this solved my problem! Do you know why i face the StaleElementReferenceException problem when I return to the page?

Comment: StaleElementException occurs because you are holding a reference of the element but the page has changed. In your case, you maintain a list of containers (list of references), when you come back to the page, the browser re-renders the elements, and so your list of references are no longer valid for this fresh new page.